# Disable columns by default in SlickGrid

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

Iv'e been looking around but didn't find (this pretty obvious functionalliy?) of disabling columns by default in slickgrid.

For example I have the following grid:

```
Name    Age     City     Nickname
```

I wish for example, to disable `city` column, and make it visible only when the user goes to the custom column picker, and enables it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Kind of a late answer, but you can just pass in another array object when creating the column picker control.

```
var defaultColumns = [
{id: "1", name: "1st Column" field: "Name"},
{id: "2", name: "2st Column" field: "Age"}
],
allColumns = [
{id: "1", name: "1st Column" field: "Name"},
{id: "2", name: "2st Column" field: "Age"}
{id: "3", name: "3st Column" field: "Gender"},
{id: "4", name: "4st Column" field: "Status"}
];

//create grid and pass in defaultColumns
 grid = new Slick.Grid("#List", dataView, defaultColumns, options)

//create the column control and pass in the allColumns
columnpicker = new Slick.Controls.ColumnPicker(allColumns, grid, options, "#List");
```

This will initialize the grid with the default columns and set the control to contain all available columns. It doesnt look like the slickgrid wiki contains the proper documentation on column picker control, I only know because I had to dig into the code and add a button to reset the view.

Obligatory ref link: https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Slick.Grid

Comment: Is there also an event that triggers when a column gets toggled using the columnpicker?

Answer (score 0):

I've done like this.

```
var org_columns = [],hid_columns = [];
org_columns.push(
cb_selector.getColumnDefinition(),
{id: "id", name: "ID", field: "id", sortable: true, width: 56},
{id: "name", name: "Name", field: "name", editor: Slick.Editors.Text, sortable: true, width: 234},
{id: "email", name: "Email", field: "email", editor: Slick.Editors.Text, sortable: true, width: 234}
);

hid_columns.push(
cb_selector.getColumnDefinition(),
{id: "name", name: "Name", field: "name", editor: Slick.Editors.Text, sortable: true, width: 234},
{id: "email", name: "Email", field: "email", editor: Slick.Editors.Text, sortable: true, width: 234}
);
var data_view = new Slick.Data.DataView();
grid = new Slick.Grid("#grid", data_view, hid_columns, grid_options);
var columnPicker= new Slick.Controls.ColumnPicker(org_columns, grid,grid_options);
```

Answer (score -1):

After a quick RTFM of SlickGrid I think simplest way is to just manipulate it's classes with JS/JQ - as you can see in developer tools every column and row has classes that defines rows and columns:

```
<div class="ui-widget-content slick-row even" style="top:0px"><div class="slick-cell l0 r0">Task 0</div><div class="slick-cell l1 r1">5 days</div><div class="slick-cell l2 r2">92</div><div class="slick-cell l3 r3">01/01/2009</div><div class="slick-cell l4 r4">01/05/2009</div><div class="slick-cell l5 r5">true</div></div>
<div class="ui-widget-content slick-row odd" style="top:25px"><div class="slick-cell l0 r0">Task 1</div><div class="slick-cell l1 r1">5 days</div><div class="slick-cell l2 r2">35</div><div class="slick-cell l3 r3">01/01/2009</div><div class="slick-cell l4 r4">01/05/2009</div><div class="slick-cell l5 r5">false</div></div>
```

From: http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example1-simple.html

So it should be very easy :)